# Why does excluding a ] to the test command [ not stop script execution?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a Bash script as the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "1" -eq "1"
then echo "something"
else echo "some other thing"
fi
```

When i execute the script, I get the following output

```
test.sh: line 2: [: missing `]'
some other thing
```

which is unclear to me, as I excepted the script to exit with an error. Can this be explained in more detail if it is an expected behavior?

However when i use the compound command `[[`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "1" == "1"
then echo "something"
else echo "some other thing"
fi
```

i do get the error and the script stops executing further.

```
test.sh: line 2: syntax error in conditional expression
test.sh: line 3: syntax error near `then'
test.sh: line 3: `then echo "something"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is not bash syntax, it's just a command (a command with a shell-builtin implementation available as a performance optimization, yes, but subject to the same parse-time behavior as the standard `/bin/[` external implementation or any other command). Putting an invalid `ping` command or an invalid `grep` command in the same position doesn't make your script's syntax invalid either.

By contrast, `[[` *is* actual syntax, which is what makes the features it has over `[` ([a set which includes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) recognizing patterns without expanding them as globs, suppressing string-splitting and glob expansion, letting `&&` and `||` to be used to combine tests, etc) possible, and also makes invalid usage able to cause a parse error.

---

If you want to reduce confusion to readers, consider using the name `test` in place of `[`. While `[` and `test` are typically aliases to the same command (with the only difference in behavior being whether `]` is required), it's much more visually clear to readers that `if test 1 -eq 1; then` is running a command named `test` and not some kind of special shell syntax.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you for the edit. I'm a little hesitant to bring the use of `<` and `>` in `[[ ]]` up without clarifying that they're only for lexicographic and not numeric comparisons, so I've chosen a different set of examples.

Comment: Even better ^__^

Answer (score 1):

```
$ type [[ [
[[ is a shell keyword
[ is a shell builtin
```

`[` is an ordinary built-in. `[[` is a shell keyword, and it has special syntactic significance (e.g., variables do not undergo word splitting). So an invalid usage of `[[` can be a parsing error, stopping the script from being parsed correctly, whereas similar usage of `[` is just the built-in returning a non-zero exit code with possibly some error output. It makes no more difference to the shell than does, say, `false` returning a non-zero exit code.